# Are vague or speculative questions ever on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I just noticed that there are several questions tagged [vague](/questions/tagged/vague), [speculative](/questions/tagged/speculative), and [future](/questions/tagged/future). Aside from one or two questions that actually relate to the computer use of the word "speculative" (as in "speculative execution"), the questions all seem fairly poor.

Examples of some poor questions:

- [Taking Arabic Character Input in C++ from a console application on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3889792/310574): "Is there any Code How to take Arabic Input from user in C++ ?"
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604139/navigating-through-a-sea-of-hype: "This is a vague, open question, so if you have no interest in these, please leave now."
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330763/when-will-silverlight-4-come-out-what-features-will-it-have: "When will Silverlight 4 come out?"
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296297/what-optimizations-today-are-going-to-be-useless-tomorrow
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985545/will-html5-change-everything-for-designers: "What impact do you think html5 will have on the workflow/way graphic design is done for the web?"

Are these relics of the past that should be allowed to stay? Should they be closed? Some third option?

Comment: Aren't those meta-tags and should be removed?

Comment: `future` might be valid when the question is about [futures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_(programming)).

Comment: Just don't remove the tags until we nuke those questions

Answer (score 1):

If you go over the questions of these tags, most of them seem to be genuine questions tough and people have answered and upvoted as well. Some questions which do not make sense have already been closed anyway.

Probably only solution here would be to delete these tags from the question than deleting or closing the question itself.

Comment: +1 I voted to close most of the negative scored questions in these tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are perfect tags to destroy.  Too bad [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) was burninated...

I vote to remove these tags & I would like to add [future-programming](/questions/tagged/future-programming) to the list & only mention it as this gem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531075/the-next-level-of-programming-approach

will be left without any tags.  Votes to delete?

Comment: Time gone by I would have said migrate to programmers.se, but we've been instructed Don't Migrate Crap, so here, have a third delete vote :)